# Is there a data structure to do the following:

Tags: java, list, data-structures

When I input a certain data item (character here), I can access the elements it relates to like:

When I input 'A', it gives me access to the values `(2, 3, 4, 5)`, e.g.:

```
A - 2,3,4,5   
B - 6,7,9  
C - 10, 11, 12, 13  
D - 1,8
and so on...
```

Also that `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` could be any data item, `int` or even a string.

What I am thinking is, I can hold on a linear array and then each item in the array be the header for a linked list. Is this a correct and optimal solution to the above data structure required? Do we already have some data structure to do this?

Comment: Is your question language-specific? If so, precise it.

Comment: Does it need to maintain order?

Comment: @Julien Bourdon - C++, Java

Comment: @tjameson - Yes order is important

Comment: Added a Java example in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to use a [Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) with an array (or list) in the table value.

Here an example in Java using HashMap

```
Map<String,Integer[]> theMap;
theMap = new HashMap<String,Integer[]>();
theMap.put("A",{2,3,4,5});
theMap.put("B",{6,7,9});
theMap.put("C",{10,11,12,13});
theMap.put("D",{1,8});

/* Access Values */
int two = theMap.get("A")[0];
```

You could also use `ArrayList` instead of arrays for your integers.

The code would become as follows:

```
ArrayList<Integer> listA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    listA.add(2);
    listA.add(3);
    listA.add(4);
    listA.add(4);

ArrayList<Integer> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
    listB.add(6);
    listB.add(7);
    listB.add(9);

ArrayList<Integer> listC = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    listC.add(10);
    listC.add(11);
    listC.add(12);
    listC.add(13);

ArrayList<Integer> listD = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    listD.add(1);
    listD.add(18);

    Map<String,List<Integer>> theMap;
    theMap = new HashMap<String,List<Integer>>();
    theMap.put("A",listA);
    theMap.put("B",listB);
    theMap.put("C",listC);
    theMap.put("D",listD);

    /* Access Values */
    int two = theMap.get("A").get(0);
```

Comment: Thanks Julien Bourdon, this really helps.

Comment: I get an error:"not a statement" in this line:
theMap.put("A", {2,3,4,5});
and the similar lines..

I tried the following:
Integer []numbers = {2,3,4,5};
String key = "A";
theMap.put(key, numbers);

and it goes fine. 
Is there a difference in both of these pieces of code ?

I am using Jdk1.7

Comment: I haven't tested the code, but indeed, you might not be able to specify the the array directly in the method. Anyway, I would suggest you use a list instead of an array as they are easier to work with and closer to the OO philosophy.

Comment: @KaranSharma modified the answer with lists.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple [dictionary/map/associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) whose elements are lists (or sets). In Python, a [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) can help here:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
A,B,C,D = ['A', 8, 3.0, (1,2)]
d[A].extend([2, 3, 4])
d[A].append(5)
# d[A] is now [2,3,4,5]
```